# How to put data from loop into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops

I have this array that looks like this.

```
@a = ["foo","bar"].join(",")
```

But i would like to retrieve the "foo" and "bar" through a loop from my database instead of creating them manually and insert them into the array. How would i do that? For instance i have data, in which i want all the usernames to be put in an array and be seperated by the ",". How can i put all usernames into the array?

```
@data = Data.all

@data.each do |d|
   d.username
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usernames = Data.all.map(&:username)
joined = usernames.join(',')
```

Comment: Your first answer worked, thanks. Data.all.map(&:username).join(',')